# Update PHP version 5.3 to 7.2 Amazon aws ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to update PHP version 5.3 to 7.2. but this does not update .his give me some error. Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64 Error: php70-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64 Error: mysql56-server conflicts with mysql55-server-5.5.60-1.21.amzn1.x86_64 Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 Error: perl-DBD-MySQL56 conflicts with perl-DBD-MySQL55-4.023-5.23.amzn1.x86_64 Error: mysql56-server conflicts with mysql-server-5.5-1.6.amzn1.noarch Error: php70 conflicts with php-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the newer versions, remove the older versions that are already installed.

For example, if you have the yum package manager:

```
sudo yum remove httpd-tools-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64 httpd-2.2.34-1.16.amzn1.x86_64 php-cli-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 mysql55-server-5.5.60-1.21.amzn1.x86_64 perl-DBD-MySQL55-4.023-5.23.amzn1.x86_64 mysql-server-5.5-1.6.amzn1.noarch php-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
```